# How to use tap on Macbook Pro with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, macbook, touchpad

I have a new Macbook Pro with Mac OSX and Windows7. Tapping the touchpad works with Windows using VM and Bootcamp but not when I boot direct into Windows7. Anyone know how I can get the tap function to work? Thanks.